# How does one translate expressions like "PC Master Race" or "Ultrawide master race" into Chinese?

Tags: translation

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC_Master_Race
https://www.reddit.com/r/ultrawidemasterrace/

Surely a meme like this would find its way into eastern culture one way or the other.  I've only seen a reddit user with this attempt: https://www.reddit.com/r/pcmasterrace/comments/27xix4/spreading_the_word_of_the_master_race_to_other/

Comment: There’s a couple of translations I’ve found: PC Master Race(PC优等民族), “荣耀的PC优等种族”(Glorious PC Gaming Master Race

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC_Master_Race) :

> the term is used by PC enthusiasts both to describe themselves as a
>   group, as well as their belief in the superiority of the PC platform
>   in comparison to consoles, often citing features like more advanced
>   graphics, smoother framerates, free online play, backwards
>   compatibility, modifications, upgradability, customization, lower
>   cost-over-time, open standards, multitasking, and performance.

Here I have to mention two words that is related to this term in Chinese culture:

`鄙视链 a chain of contempt`,

`优越感 superiority`.

Naturally, `PC Master Race` means `PC优等民族`, `Glorious PC Gaming Master Race` can be directly translated to `高贵的PC玩家`, which is often seen among Chinese gamers, and is less "racism". To `Ultrawide master race` you can say `高贵的超宽屏用户`